# Android: Few characters missing from server text for Internationalization

Tags: android, string, localization, internationalization, locale

I am working on an Android app which supports few other locales apart from English (like PTBr). I get the text from server in PTBr (Brazilian Portuguese) and I display it as it is in a Text view. I have also set my phone's locale to PTBr but still don't see the complete text. A few characters are missing.
I am stressing on "server-data" since I don't have it locally, and thus I can't put it in res-string folders.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you perhaps give some more detail about the missing characters? Are the strings truncated (always the last few characters missing)? Are certain characters never visible?

Comment: Hi, it's basically the special characters which are not visible. For example, "Serviços" is displayed as "Servi os".

Comment: In that case you probably have some kind of mixed encoding issue, using for example utf-8 in some places and iso-8859-1 elsewhere. I am afraid I don't know an easy way to debug this except looking at the bytes returned from every server call where you expect to get extended character back.

Another possibility could be that you are using a font that does not support the extended characters that occur in Portuguese, but I would have expected that a fallback character would be displayed in that case.